# postgres trunc_date removing a month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following procedure for Postgres which will be used for generating the names for different table's partitions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_partition_name(table_name VARCHAR, archived_on TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $get_partition_name$
DECLARE
    partition_date TIMESTAMP := date_trunc('month', archived_on, 'Universal');
BEGIN

    RETURN CONCAT(table_name, to_char(partition_date, '"_y"YYYY"m"MM'));
    
END;
$get_partition_name$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run the function I get the correct formatted string, but the month is off:

```
SELECT get_partition_name('george', '2024-03-06 12:39:48.399 -0500');
RESULT: george_y2024m02
```

Why is it removing a month? Even when you convert it manually from EST to UTC, it doesn't take you back that far. When I remove the `UTC` parameter from the declaration, it seems work work fine though?

```
SELECT get_partition_name('george', '2024-03-06 12:39:48.399 -0500');
RESULT: george_y2024m03
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html): *When the input value is of type timestamp with time zone, the truncation is performed with respect to a particular time zone; for example, truncation to day produces a value that is midnight in that zone. By default, truncation is done with respect to the current TimeZone setting, but the optional time_zone argument can be provided to specify a different time zone.*

Comment: I would have thought that it would truncate the March 01 00:00:00? What piece am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be working for me [working fiddle this time](https://dbfiddle.uk/0VDfny4c)

Comment: @Andrew That's because you forgot to ass OP's `SET TimeZone='EST';`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3DY2oILQ). Adrian Klaver above is right on the money.

Comment: I just ran 'show timezone' and got 'America/New_York'. Is this supposed to indicate there's a difference between the two?

Comment: @Kirkland No, NYC is in EST. I think you just don't want the third parameter in `date_trunc()` at all, or you want it to be `current_setting('TimeZone'::text)`, unless *do* want that shifting. It's truncating to March 1 midnight first in `UTC`/`Universal`, and then shifting that to your currently set TimeZone which is `EST`/`America,/New_York`, 5h back to 7pm on Feb 29th. You can `raise notice '%',partition_date::text;` right before `return` to see that the timestamp arrives to your to_char as that moment, 5h ahead of March 1st: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/wOamrbhU)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think I'm catching up to what you're saying, thanks! Re-write your response as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per docs [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

> When the input value is of type timestamp with time zone, the truncation is performed with respect to a particular time zone; for example, truncation to day produces a value that is midnight in that zone. By default, truncation is done with respect to the current TimeZone setting, but the optional time_zone argument can be provided to specify a different time zone. The time zone name can be specified in any of the ways described in Section 8.5.3.

```
show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 EST

select date_trunc('month', '2024-03-06 12:39:48.399 -0500'::timestamptz);
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2024-03-01 00:00:00-05

select date_trunc('month', '2024-03-06 12:39:48.399 -0500'::timestamptz, 'UTC');
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2024-02-29 19:00:00-05
```

The first case uses the `timezone` of `EST` and deals with the timestamp as it where in the time zone. This means truncating to midnight of first day of the month.

The second case is truncating the date to the month for a value of `2024-03-01 00:00:00` at `UTC` and the rotating that to the `timezone` of `EST`.

Essentially:

```
select ('2024-03-01 00:00:00+00' at time zone 'EST')::timestamptz ;
        timezone        
------------------------
 2024-02-29 19:00:00-05
```